# Were Devore's assumptions regarding Poisson processes incorrect?

Tags: probability-theory, poisson-process

Page 134 of Devore's 9th Edition [Probability and Statistics for Engineering and the Sciences](https://www.cengage.com/c/probability-and-statistics-for-engineering-and-the-sciences-9e-devore/9781305251809PF/) lists the following two assumptions regarding Poisson processes:

1. There exists a parameter $α > 0$ such that for any short time interval of length $∆t$, the probability that exactly one event occurs is $α \cdot ∆t + o(∆t)$.
2. The probability of more than one event occurring during $∆t$ is $o(∆t)$ [which, along with Assumption 1, implies that the probability of no events during $∆t$ is $1 - α \cdot ∆t - o(∆t)$].

...where a quantity is $o(∆t)$ if, as $∆t$ approaches $0$, so does $o(∆t)$/$∆t$.

I see two apparent issues with the above:

1. I don't see how these equations can yield probabilities. To illustrate, Example 3.41 gives $α = 6$ and $∆t = 0.5$, which would leave us with a probability greater than one.
2. For the math to work, I believe "exactly one" in the first assumption should be "at least one" instead. Alternatively, the "+ $ o(∆t)$" term should be deleted from that sentence.

Or am I just missing something obvious here? To my knowledge, there is no published errata for this textbook.

Following is Example 3.41, for reference:

Suppose pulses arrive at a counter at an average rate of six per minute, so that $\alpha = 6$. To find the probability that in a $.5$-min interval at least one pulse is received, note that the number of pulses in such an interval has a Poisson distribution with parameter $\alpha t = 6(.5) = 3$ ($.5$ min is used because $\alpha$ is expressed as a rate per minute). Then with $X=$ the number of pulses received in the $30$-sec interval,

$P(1≤X) = 1-P(X=0) = 1-\frac{e^{-3}(3)^0}{0!}=.950$

Comment: Write your question so that nobody has to shell out $32 to understand it. What is "example 3.4.1"?

Comment: The statement 1 and 2 only work in the limit as $\Delta t \to 0$, and in particular, it provides no qualitative control over the probabilities for each given $\Delta t$. (That is, this does not give any specific information about the size of the error $o(\Delta t)$ if $\Delta t$ is fixed.) As such, one should not expect, *a priori*, to use either of the conditions to compute probabilities regarding Poisson processes. Such computations will become available only after the properties of the Poisson processes have been established.

Comment: Maybe you want to brush up on little o notation.  The statement in (1) means that $\lim_{\Delta t \to 0} \frac{P(\text{1 event}) - \alpha \Delta t}{\Delta t} = 0$, no more and no less.  As a limit statement it says nothing whatever about $\Delta t = 0.5$ specifically.

Answer (score 2):

"Exactly one" and "at least one" both work equally well in the first statement.

If $\alpha$ is the rate of the Poisson process, then

- the probability of *at least one* event occurring in an interval of length $h$ is exactly $1 - e^{-\alpha h}$.
- the probability of *exactly one* event occurring in an interval of length $h$ is exactly $e^{-\alpha h} \cdot \alpha h$.

We have $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1 - e^{-\alpha h} - \alpha h}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\alpha e^{-\alpha h} - \alpha}{1} = 0$ by L'Hopital's rule, so $1 - e^{-\alpha h} = \alpha h + o(h)$.

We also have $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{e^{-\alpha h} \cdot \alpha h - \alpha h}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} (\alpha e^{-\alpha h} - \alpha) = 0$, so $e^{-\alpha h} \cdot \alpha h = \alpha h + o(h)$.

Note that this does not imply that these probabilities are the same! Two different expressions can both be $o(h)$.

---

In example 3.4.1, $\alpha = 6$ and $\Delta t = 0.5$ do not contradict the claim that $\alpha \Delta t + o(\Delta t)$ is a probability.

It just means that $o(\Delta t)$ stands in for a term which is asymptotically less than $\Delta t$ as $\Delta t \to 0$, but is negative (in fact, $-2$ or less) at the specific point you're looking at here.

Comment: Thanks Misha. I've added example 3.41 above, per your request. Your equations for "at least one" and "exactly one" in the bulleted list are correct, but I don't understand your limits (perhaps partly due to my rusty/incomplete calculus), and it looks like "so $e^{ah}$" from the last line of your response should be "so $e^{-ah}$" instead. I'm having a hard time believing that the probability of exactly one event is equal to the probability of at least one event (as you conclude in the last two lines), especially considering the equations in your bulleted list aren't equal.

Comment: I've tried to edit my answer to address some of these concerns (and to correct the typo you pointed out). I think the big thing that you're missing is that $o(\Delta t)$ doesn't have to stand in for a *fixed* value. We have $1 - e^{-\alpha h} = \alpha h + o(h)$ and $\alpha h e^{-\alpha h} = \alpha h + o(h)$, where the $o(h)$ stands for two *different* functions that are asymptotically less than $h$ as $h \to 0$. So we're not concluding that the probabilities are equal.

Comment: Thanks again, Misha, that would indeed help to resolve my confusion... If such loose notation (i.e., using one function to represent two different functions in a single list of assumptions) is common among academics, I feel sorry for their students!

Answer (score 1):

Regarding issue 1, note that when we are using the o notations and all, we are talking about infinitesimal time intervals such that $\alpha \Delta t \ll 1$ which is certainly not the case in your example.

Regarding the 2nd issue, everything is correct; the probability for exactly one event to occur, also has some $o(\Delta t)$ terms. The exact expression is
$$e^{-\alpha \Delta t}\alpha \Delta t = \alpha \Delta t -\alpha^2 \Delta t^2 +\frac12\alpha^3\Delta t^3-\cdots = \alpha \Delta t + o(\Delta t)$$

Comment: Thanks K. It looks like you're using the Maclaurin series expansion here. If so, for completeness, it'd probably be a good idea to show the third term so it's clear you're (silently) dividing by factorials, agreed? The first term is divided by $0!$ and the second is divided by $1!$, which both equal $1$, so they disappear. But the third term would be divided by $2!$.

Comment: Yes, I am using the Taylor series here. Ok, here you go :))